# Using mvc design pattern in php driven web applications

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I have been reading tutorials and questions about mvc on stackoverflow lately and I need to ask a couple of questions to see if I understand the basic concepts correctly.

- To my understanding, having only one view object for rendering multiple views (html files) is enough most of the time. Is this correct?
- Is putting the presentation logic in view files is better than putting it in view object to avoid adding extra complexity to the view layer?
- It is known to be good practice to have one index page and autoloading controllers from there based on request urls and file names. But, doesn't that mean having controllers for every request url? Is it ok to group some of the request urls and map them to one controller. (Having multiple if-else statements on index page or putting the information in an array config file)
- If I have one view object, than the relationship with this object and the controllers must be 1:1. Is this true?
- Lastly, If I need to pass big amount of information from controller to the view, and some of that information is repeated in other controllers; than is it a good way to handle those repeated information in base controller, which is the parent of other controllers?

As you see, I'm still confused. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this is a intresting question... As a general rule MVC was designed to decouple these 3 commonly intertwined components.

If your model cannot support multiple views at the same time, its not MVC

If your model speaks to your controller, or even knows about its existance (this applies to the view also) then its not MVC.

If you have a 1:1 ratio between view and controller its most likely not MVC. 
You should be able to swap out any of those 3 components from the system with primarily only config changes.

Its a extremely misused term, and often 'attempts' at MVC end up with the extremely coupled code that the concept of MVC was designed to work around.

Comment: When saying view, do you mean html template files or the object that renders those files?

Comment: @Whiteley Well this depends on the design of your application. At the moment I am writing a fair bit of code which has PHP for controller and model ( so have php provide JSON responses to data requests, and have php code which takes parameters for create, update, and delete operations. ) and and the rest of the application (which happens to be the view) is all written in plain static HTML and javascript. (making the html the view) In this situation if the entire application was changed from php to lets say java servlets there would be no code changes required for the view.

Comment: when I said 1:1 relationship between controller and view, I meant view renderer. Sorry, I was technical more than conceptual. Otherwise, I'm aware that I need more than 10 views for my login controller.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do MVC with PHP.

One class supporting everything (global controller).
It load your classes, it process the URI to know which controller start, it check your data (GET, POST), it check the user session (is it expired?, is there someone logged in? Is he an admin?).

Many classes supporting the interactivity (controllers).
A class managing your News, a class managing your Users, etc...
With static methods doing every user to model action.
Basically "add a new item", "delete an item", "update an item".

Many classes telling how things are organized (model).
Your user have a login, an hashed password, an email adress, etc...
See DAO for more information. (basically, all SQL is in these classes). These classes check nothing except that data given are as expected.

Many classes telling how to show things (views).
Called by a Controller which give what is needed (object, array, output data)
The only place where you have HTML and where the more complicated is a loop in a loop creating a whole HTML .
You will have one showing "a message in a centered box", one showing "a list of element", one showing "a single element", one showing "a single element, with an author sidebar", etc.

HTML Templates/Elements are useful to build your view, but it's the view who call templates/Elements and place them how the view want.